# Express and Sequelize - Returning all child data from a parent id returns Promise

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, sequelize.js, backend

I have three tables with the following structure and data:

```
quote_tags
id | quote_id | tag_id
1     1          1
2     1          2
3     2          3
```

```
tags
tag_id | tag_name
1        business
2        health 
3        finance
```

```
quote
quote_id   | quote 
1          Sample quote 1          
2          Sample quote 2
```

The target query is that I should be able to get every `tag_name` and `tag_id` that is associated with a single `quote id` via the `quote_tags` table.

The target response should be like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "quote": "Sample quote 2",
        "tag": [
            {
               "tag_id" : 3,
               "tag_name": "finance"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "quote": "Sample quote 1",
        "tag": [
              {
               "tag_id" : 2,
               "tag_name": "health"
            },  {
               "tag_id" : 1,
               "tag_name":"business"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my express and sequelize code for it.

```
  // Join quote_tags and tags table
  QuoteTags.hasMany(Tags, { foreignKey: "tag_id" });
  Tags.belongsTo(QuoteTags, { foreignKey: "tag_id" }, { targetKey: "tag_id" });

  let allQuotesArray = [];
  let finalArray = [];
  let tagArray = [];
  let tempObj = {};

  // Fetch all quotes
  allQuotesArray = await Quote.findAll({
    order: [["id", "DESC"]],
    limit: 6,
  })
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });

  finalArray = allQuotesArray.map((el) => {
    // Find all tags with same quote id
    tempObj = QuoteTags.findAll({
      include: [{ model: Tags }],
      where: {
        quote_id: el.id,
      },
    })
      .then(async (quoteTags) => {
        // Return all tags in the appropriate quote id
        tempObj = await quoteTags.map((quoteTag) => {
          quoteTag.dataValues.admin_tags.map(({ tag_id, name }) => {
            // console.log(tag_id, name);
            return { tag_id, name };
          });
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });

    tagArray.push(tempObj);

    el.dataValues.tag = tagArray;
    return el;
  });

  res.json(finalArray);
```

I've already achieved fetching all quotes id, but when returning the tags data in the `quoteTags` section of the `.then` block, the result returned is `Promise { <pending> }` even though the `tag_data` is already accessible there. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to use `Promise.all`, and you will want to `await` it.

Comment: You should drop the `await` on the synchronous `quoteTags.map(…)`, and drop the pointless `.catch((err) => { throw err; });` and `.then((data) => { return data; })`

Comment: Where exactly should I place the `Promise.all` code? I've tried placing it on the `quoteTag.dataValues.admin_tags.map` but still it returns a Promise. Thanks for answering btw

Comment: On the `allQuotesArray.map((el) => {…})` - and the callback function there should `return` the promise so that you get an array of promises to pass into `Promise.all`.

Comment: I'll try this, thank you so much for answering.

Comment: I tried placing `await Promise.all` to the `.map` and then added a `.then` as the callback function of `await Promise.all` to return the data but it still returns a `Promise` when I do `res.json(finalArray)`. This is the updated code https://pastebin.com/rDQB7g1b

Comment: I meant `return tempObj;` instead of `tagArray.push(tempObj);`. If you were going to use `tagArray`, you wouldn't need to use `map`, and had to call `Promise.all(tagArray)`.